# TinyMCE 6.0 forced root block option

Tags: tinymce

I understand option `forced_root_block` will be removed from TinyMCE version 6.0. I use this option to avoid paragraphs (generate br tags instead of p tags).

```
  forced_root_block : false
```

How am I supposed to avoid white lines in the forthcoming version of TinyMCE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this feature was already there at the time of this question but the `newline behaviour` option is the solution for me:

```
newline behaviour: "linebreak"
```

I wonder where this long time resistance against the `br` tag by the developer of TinyMCE comes from, because no one wants a new paragraph when using just one enter. Or having `br` replaced with paragraphs when you paste text from Notepad. Two `br` tags is another thing. In my scenario I convert two `br` tags into paragraphs after editing, to be able to style the white line height. Perhaps this approach does not fit in the philosophy of TinyMCE, where HTML inside and outside the editor should be seamless the same.

Answer (score 1):

There's a big discussion about this on GitHub:
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/discussions/7342

CSS `margin` is our recommended way to remove whitespace between paragraphs, but we have logged a ticket to look at how we can address the need for `br` tags:
https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/discussions/7342#discussioncomment-2129636

Answer (score 0):

Use newline_behavior : "linebreak", as it forces "Enter+shift" on every enter pressed. Whereas if "invert" is used instead of "linebreak", then the "enter" fuctionality and "shift + enter" functionality swaps.

Answer (score 0):

In tinymce 6, if I set the forced_root_block property to a non-tag value, tenter code herehen no tag was added by the editor (I expected the default value - paragraph)

```
forced_root_block: 'aaa',
```

EDIT:
I figured out it's not good solution, because its break down other functionalities